# SDL Error: Invalid Renderer on SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface

Tags: c++, sdl, renderer, sdl-image

Alrighty, from what I have researched, it appears that the Invalid Renderer error applies to a variety of cases and I'm lost onto why my code is creating it.
I have narrowed it down to a specific area of code

```
//If existing texture is there, free's and sets to NULL. Along with iWidth & iHeight = 0;
freetexture();

//final image texture
SDL_Texture* niTexture = NULL;

//Loads image at specified path
SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
if (loadedSurface == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to load image %s! SDL_image Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), IMG_GetError());
}
else
{
    printf("SpriteSheet :: Loaded\n");
    Init mkey;
    //Color key DOUBLE CHECK IF ERROR CHANGE TO ORIGINAL 0, 0xFF, 0xFF
    SDL_SetColorKey(loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(loadedSurface->format, 50, 96, 166));

    //create texture from surface pixels
    niTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(mkey.Renderer, loadedSurface);
    if (niTexture == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to create texture from %s! SDL Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), SDL_GetError());
    }
```

Specifically at the line,

```
niTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(mkey.Renderer, loadedSurface);
```

is causing SDL to return an Invalid renderer error. In my init class, the renderer initializes perfectly, only when I attempt to use it to load an image am I getting the Invalid Renderer error. Any help on how to fix this error is appreciated.

Edit::
Here's some code from the Init Class relating to the renderer,

```
printf("Linear Texture Filtering :: Enabled\n");
        //Create Window
        Window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, sw, sh, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (Window == NULL)
        {
            printf("Window failed to be created\n");
            SDLSuccess = false;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Window :: Created\n");
            //Create VYNC'd renderer for the window
            Renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(Window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
            if (Renderer == NULL)
            {
                printf("Renderer failed to be created\n");
                SDLSuccess = false;

            }
```

Hope this helps with finding the issue.

Comment: Can you show some code from the Init class?

Comment: Added some Init code for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `Renderer` isn't initialized, unless the code you posted is in the constructor of your `Init` class.

Do you already have an instance of `Init` somewhere in your code that you mean to be referencing in your texture method? Check the value of your Renderer before you try to use it, something like:

```
if (mkey.Renderer) {
    niTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(mkey.Renderer, loadedSurface);
    if (niTexture == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to create texture from %s! SDL Error: %s\n", path.c_str(), SDL_GetError());
    }
} else {
    printf("Renderer is not initialized");
}
```

Comment: That worked in fixing the invalid Renderer part, I thought since I had already set the renderer to initialize in my main, it would work if I referenced it in another class. Now I'm receiving another error regarding the actual use of the function to display an image. I'll do some more research and see if I can fix it.